# A word with two meanings though misuse could be lethal

Tags: context

I'm currently writing an article that includes two contexts of communication: effectiveness and competence. Incompetent people can misuse terminology all day and the ideas are effective and do technically work. However I'm looking for a word or term that has two or more meanings and the misuse of could lead to bodily harm or even death; this is to promote the idea of the aspect of competently communicating one's ideas.

What word if not used competently could end up leading to injury or death in a context that most people could understand with little-to-no explanation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57090/discussion-on-question-by-john-a-word-with-two-meanings-though-misuse-could-be-l).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Does it have to be a single word?

Derek Bentley was [convicted of the murder of a policeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derek_Bentley_case) in 1952 and hanged the following year. He and an accomplice, Christopher Craig, were burgling a warehouse and Craig was armed with a pistol.  When the police cornered Bentley and Craig, Craig drew the gun.  A policeman told Craig to give him the gun and Bentley allegedly responded, "**Let him have it**, Chris."  Craig shot the policeman in the shoulder and later shot another policeman dead.

During the trial, the prosecution claimed that "Let him have it" meant "shoot him", whereas the defence claimed that, if Bentley had said those words at all, he meant "give the gun to him."

Bentley was subsequently posthumously pardoned in 1993 and his conviction quashed in 1998, because of a multitude of problems, not least Bentley's mental state, an apparently falsified confession and the trial judge failing to properly direct the jury.

Comment: Outstanding answer!

Comment: The OP brought this case to my mind, too. Travesty of 'justice'. Bentley didn't even fire the gun. And how nice to be pardoned.

Comment: Just to clarify, was Bentley *posthumously* pardoned in 1993 and then had his conviction *posthumously* quashed in 1993? Or did they botch his hanging in 1953 so badly that he lived for another 45 years?

Comment: @TylerH It was posthumous. I assumed that was obvious but I've edited it in.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I assumed it was the case as well; the most likely alternative in my mind was that maybe you meant to say Craig was posthumously pardoned, not Bentley. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @TylerH Craig was only 16 at the time of the murder, so the death penalty wasn't an option. He served ten years in prison. There's more information in the Wikipedia page I linked.

Comment: Under the Felony Murder Rule, it's irrelevant.  Bentley was committing a felony, so any deaths resulting from that act are considered murder.  In the recent Oklahoma case where someone shot three burglars, their getaway driver (and apparently the leader of the gang) who was outside in her car has been charged with three counts of murder for the deaths of her accomplices.

Comment: I'm far behind on work though I'm trying to read through these. I haven't everything yet but **wow**, that is an example any native English speaker will get with little explanation and is likely what I'll accept. However to be fair I'm going to postpone that until I have the time to go through all the other answers. I'll up-vote it in the meantime, thank you for the excellent answer!

Answer (score 70):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but might work in the context.

**[inflammable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/flammable-or-inflammable)**

Many people see the "in" as a negative prefix, and believe anything marked inflammable is flame retardant.  However, both ***flammable*** and ***inflammable*** have the *same meaning*:

> ...both mean "capable of being easily ignited and of burning quickly." This makes no sense to the Modern English speaker. In English, we think of in- as a prefix that means "not": inactive means "not active," inconclusive means "not conclusive," inconsiderate means "not considerate." Therefore, *inflammable should mean "not flammable."*

-Merriam Webster

Because of this, volatile or combustible materials are often labeled  as "flammable" to avoid a potentially hazardous misinterpretation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57139/discussion-on-answer-by-cascabel-a-word-with-two-meanings-though-misuse-could-be).

Answer (score 30):

Here are some examples:

> When replacing a water pump, one must be sure to get the timing right in order to avoid damaging the engine.

In this case 'the timing' could be misconstrued as the time of day, as opposed to the timing of the engine.  This omission really can wreck an engine.

> These snakes are not poisonous.

This is tangential to your purpose, but a precise statement using a word like 'poisonous', which people think is synonymous with venomous, could easily misinform a reader. [To be clear, being venomous is about your bite being toxic, being poisonous is about if you being bitten is toxic.]

> Be sure to change the water in your fish tank bimonthly.

Poor fish, bimonthly means both twice a month and every other month. (biweekly has the same problem.)

Comment: The biweekly/monthly seems useful for an example of a misunderstanding about medical treatment.

Comment: There are also the **hemi-** and **semi-** prefixes, but most people don't use them nowadays due — probably — to lingual atrophy.

Comment: @m69 this is exactly the reason we have "forthnightly"

Comment: All venomous snakes are poisonous if you aren't cautious how you gut them.

Comment: I like that. If it's poisonous bad things happen if you bite it, if venomous bad things happen if it bites you.

Comment: If you are immune to it, then the venom is not poisonous at all.

Comment: @Joshua - what does gutting them have to do with anything? Snake venom is mostly harmless if eaten (unless you have an ulcer). It needs to be injected into your bloodstream to have an effect. You can drink it and nothing happens.

Answer (score 21):

One word with good potential here is *oversight* which can mean both supervision and omission. Thus *it is important to ensure oversight of the process* can mean keep an eye on it or ignore it.

Another simple example: "ensure all alarms and warning lights are set off at the end of the shift".

Wikipedia has a list of such [autoantonyms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) which could prove instructive.

Comment: I'm not convinced about this one. Sentence structure dictates that we say `there was oversight` (it was supervised or monitored) and `there was *an* oversight` (something was missed), so it should usually be clear from context.

Comment: @flith it takes a bit of twisting and my example can probably be improved on. But the word itself variesw both meanings so the confusion is present. Another version could be "Fred's oversight of the project was a key factor in the company's results last year".

Comment: `Fred's lack of oversight was an oversight.`

Comment: Actually, a certain government body had to rewrite some of their legislate due to this _exact_ word.

Comment: I'm not convinced by either of these. For the first one, something like "His oversight led to failure" would be better: could refer to either his inadequate supervision or to his omission, whereas oversight of something can only really refer to supervision. I don't think the second one works at all: "alarms set off" only really means "alarms triggered", whereas "alarms disabled" would be "alarms set _to_ off".

Comment: @DavidRicherby they're not perfect but they're close enough to cause confusion. How about "alarms set *off*" or "alarms set 'off'". I've seen signs (old railways probably) that use this sort of construction ("thing set *state*") where some form of emphasis is used instead of "to". But in general I think there's an selection process against things that are perfect answers to the OP's question, at least that sounds reasonably natural.

Comment: I think the second would be improved by italics/inverted commas.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Q. is about "*Incompetent ... misuse* [of] terminology [with] a word or term that has two or more meanings and the misuse of could lead to bodily harm or even death".  I don't dispute your suggestions that the wording of the examples *could* be better - but these are examples where poor wording *can* lead to misunderstanding with potentially fatal consequences.

Answer (score 19):

Doesn't translate in spelling - but does verbally:

"raise" vs "raze".

"Raise a barn" - means to errect/construct it

"Raze a barn" - means to burn it to the ground

Comment: The spelling difference can work well here. An incompetent person might use the wrong spelling.

Answer (score 14):

Since I've already botched this one myself, there is the prescribe/proscribe pair that can have serious unintended consequences.

**prescribe**

> 2
>   :  to designate or order the use of as a remedy prescribed a painkiller a prescribed burn to restore natural forest conditions

**proscribe**

> 2
>   :  to condemn or forbid as harmful or unlawful :  prohibit

both from MW online

Comment: This is a good one - especially as "prescribe" can also mean "make compulsory", basically the exact opposit of "proscribe" :)

Comment: This is an excellent one. If proscribe isn't in your vocabulary you think it's a typo of prescribe.

Answer (score 11):

There are many contranyms which meet your requirements. [Here is a list of 75 possible candidates](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/75-contronyms-words-with-contradictory-meanings/), including:

Cleave: to join or to separate

Dike: a wall or a ditch

Left: remaining or departed

EDIT: adding *Gust van de Wal's* comment from below:

> **Cleave:** "Yeah so there's a crack in one of the bombshells. Make sure you cleave it, otherwise it might explode"
>
> **Dike:** "Quickly, there is a tsunami coming! Go to the dike!"
>
> **Left:** *Leaving a burning building* "How about the other people??" "Nobody's left"

Comment: I don't think these necessarily convey or convey the type of overt danger the OP was looking for - but still +1 for a fun and interesting read ;-)

Comment: @Brad **Cleave**: "Yeah so there's a crack in one of the bombshells. Make sure you cleave it, otherwise it might explode" **Dike**: "Quickly, there is a tsunami coming! Go to the dike!" **Left**: *Leaving a burning building* "How about the other people??" "Nobody's left"

Comment: @GustvandeWal: "Cleave" in either sense is uncommon, the join sense more so (and usually as "cleave to"), so that seems contrived. "Dike" is also uncommon, and knowing local geography would probably clarify that one. But the "left" example has potential. I can absolutely see that being used wrongly by a non-native but generally competent English speaker. (A native speaker would almost surely say "nobody's left *yet*" or the like if that's what they meant.)

Comment: Note that in the "Nobody's left" example, the contraction is what makes it ambiguous.  "Nobody has left" vs "Nobody is left"

Comment: I'm upvoting for pointing at contranyms in general, rather than these specific examples.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you have two students, Bill and Susan, who are running from a pack of hungry beasts.  "Make yourself **fast**!" Bill shouts, calling on Susan to move more quickly.  Instead, she ties herself down to a nearby tree.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fast

> Firmly fixed or fastened.

"No, no," Bill shouts, "I mean go fast!"

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fast

> moving or able to move, operate, function, or take effect quickly; quick; swift; rapid:

Luckily, the beasts listened as well, and moved right past the both of them.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fast

> to abstain from all food.

Comment: "fasten" doesn't mean speed up or move more quickly.

Comment: @Vicky Right, "fasten" in that case is the error. As opposed to "go faster." Telling a monster to "go fast" is just the icing on the cake -- it could mean "speed up" or "abstain from eating"

Comment: -1 "Fasten" simply does not mean "make faster".

Comment: @DavidRicherby right, just like "inflammable" doesn't mean "non-flammable."  The whole point is that the statement is erroneous.  Note that I have a separate definition link for "fasten" and "fast."

Comment: OK, but believing that "inflammable" means "non-flammable" is a common mistake. There is no widespread belief that "fasten" means "hasten"; it's a contrived example that just doesn't occur in reality.

Comment: Because he suffix "-en" often means "to activate," as in "soften" or "sicken," the erroneous use of "fasten" could follow.  I'm fine with your downvote, but you're making a subjective decision about what's a reasonable mistake and what's not.  Someone familiar with "flammable" and "inflammable" in English might say the same thing.

Comment: The answer doesn't cite an example where this occured, but is it really all that inconceivable that someone, somewhere, might not know that **fast** is not the same as **haste**?  Seems to me that more people use **fast** nowadays to mean **speedy**, or the like, than to say, e.g., ‘Make it fast to that stump, Sam!’  Leastways in the english–speaking southern half of North America.

Answer (score 9):

**Hyperthermia** and **Hypothermia** in quick speech (especially in non-Rhotic dialects) can sound very similar. Similar with **hypo** and **hyper** for diabetics. The **hypo-** prefix in medicine means "deficient" whereas the **hyper-** prefix means "excessive". They therefore usually refer to conditions that are the exact opposite of each other, where the correct treatment for one can instead exacerbate the opposite condition.

Comment: This would be a better answer if the two prefixes **hyper** and **hypo** were explained, along with the consequences of getting them wrong.

Comment: Both hyper- and hypothermia kill quickly, and context normally makes it clear which one it is. A better example would be hyper- vs. hypoglycemia. Hypoglycemia is an emergency that requires immediate intervention to keep someone alive. Hyperglycemia is bad, but it kills slowly. If you say "hypoglycemia" and it's misheard as "hyper", that could lead to someone's death. (at least, in the EMT world)

Comment: Not to mention *hypothyroidism* and *hyperthyroidism*, although getting the wrong treatment here is probably less likely.

Comment: Hypo/hyperglycemia. I.e. hyper = high blood sugar in which one may administer insulin to bring the level down. Hypo would require sugary food to bring the level up. Mishearing would result in doing the exact opposite and possibly causing serious injury or death.

Answer (score 7):

I'm really not sure whether the OP is asking for words that truly have more than one CORRECT meaning(like "sanction"), or for examples or words that are commonly MIS-used or misunderstood, but here goes:

Radiologist reads an Xray and dictates into his report: "This finding obviates the need for a CT scan." The guy saying this, THINKS that **obviates** means "makes obvious," when of course it means the opposite. The physician reading the report(and applying it to his patient) takes the CORRECT meaning, which is "to prevent, remove or avoid" and doesn't order the CT scan.

Answer (score 6):

**Fire!**

In a firing squad, this command gets someone shot.

In any other circumstance, it warns that there is a danger of things being aflame.

If someone shouts it at a firing range, then it could potentially be misinterpreted in fatal ways.

- An active shooting squad could open fire, taking a life that could have been pardoned at the last minute;
- Trainers on the firing range could open fire, shooting people they didn't notice who were cleaning the range;
- It could be ignored as a warning by everyone in the vicinity in the assumption that it is a command, allowing the flames to take lives.

To be honest, the first two are unlikely in any case where the shooters have had any gun training whatsoever, but still. It's an example where context *could* kill.

Comment: There is a rather old joke based on this misunderstanding: http://ingles.akdmic.com/default.asp?page_url=jokes&jokeid=84

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it happened two years ago near where I live: [Dutch teen killed in bungee accident misunderstood verbal instructions](http://elpais.com/elpais/2015/08/12/inenglish/1439372613_916114.html)

And this is where a linguistic misunderstanding gets lethal:

> The ongoing police investigation into the accident now seems to point to a linguistic misunderstanding as a possible cause. Sources believe that the young woman thought she heard the monitor say “now jump,” instead of “no jump,” prompting her to leap off the bridge before her harness had been properly fixed.

It was the monitor's fault, obviously. Knowing correct English grammar could've saved the girl's life.

Answer (score 6):

So, you're a snowplough operator working at an airport, and you're told to "***Clear*** Runway 08 immediately!"  Do you ***start removing the snow***, or ***get out of the way*** of the incoming aircraft?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but...

I was hanging out with a group of young (20's give or take a few years) guys in a park in a moderately rough area of New Orleans (by NOLA standards. Anywhere else I've lived it would have been downright rough) in the mid 1980's. This was a deeply homophobic time, and in the deep South.

A guy visiting from Australia came up to us and asked for "a fag". It was eventually established that this was how cigarettes are referred to in his country, but there were some really tense moments there.<sup>*</sup>

In that time and place "fag" only meant you were calling someone out as a homosexual. Practically, it was used as the absolute best way to start a fight with a guy quickly if you didn't want to bother with a lot of pre-fight foreplay.

<sup>* - Lest your 2017 brain think this wasn't that serious, a few years prior to that a former friend of mine was arrested for helping beat to death a gay guy near a convenience store. The [Matthew Sheppard death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Shepard#The_murder) a decade later was only unusual that people put up a fuss about it. So yes, in that time and place this could be a life-or-death matter. The "Good old days" weren't all that good.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

"Before I go on vacation, just remember this piece of advice: you can never put too much water in the nuclear reactor"

This can either be a dire warning that too much water can cause major problems or a recommendation that when in doubt, one should flood the reactor.

Context and phrasing are unhelpful in determining the actual intent of the message and misinterpretation could cause dire consequences.

Comment: That's poor grammer.  " ... can never..." is not a correct imperative form.

Comment: Is that one meaning of "can never" is actually "should never"?

Comment: If you interpret it as a shortened form of "you can never do x without consequence y"? And IIRC, this example is interesting because with some reactor types the first interpretation is true, with others the second...

Answer (score 4):

"If we're going to have unprotected sex, I want to be certain that we don't catch anything from each other. Are you sure of your HIV status?"

"I'm **positive**."

Answer (score 3):

**Nigger**

Nigger is used as both a racial slur and term of endearment. Demonstrates how the same word can have an antipodal meaning.

EDIT: Per requests, below is a fuller elaboration of the above.

> this is to promote the idea of the aspect of competently communicating one's ideas.

Words are symbols that reflect an idea. When we communicate with another person, one assumption we are making is that our words map to the same, or at the very least, a similar idea.

Problems emerge when the idea we are trying to convey with a particular word has different meaning to our recipient. The importance of this is that in order to communicate competently, we need to appreciate that it takes more than just words in order to "speak the same language".

I think *nigger* is a good example of this, with the *N-word* and *nigga* reflecting our peculiar attempts to navigate this treacherous terrain.

By way of example, we consider the following scene from the comedy film *40 Year Old Virgin (2005).*

Here, two African-American men get into an argument. At first, nigger is used endearingly, but interpreted to mean servitude. Matters quickly escalate:

> Customer: Now don't be a negro, be my nigga. aight, help me out.
>   
> Jay: Woah woah woah hold on, I ain't nobody's nigga.
>   
> Customer: Well, I mean you's somebody's nigga, wearing this nigga tie.
>   
> Jay: Now you're being condescending. See you've been warned aight. Just move forward amicably.
>   
>   [Further antagonism by customer]
>   
>   
> Jay: Okay see, see now you found yourself a nigga. You was looking for a nigga, Nigga here now!
>
> Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmYkt2RkhsI

In the following, we note attempts to reconcile these two contrasting meanings by attempting to delineate *nigga* from *nigger*.

Disagreement about the appropriateness of this resulted in the suspension of a high school teacher. The image below is a satirisation of the event in an episode of the animated comedy *Boondocks*

[image]

The original news report may be viewed here and is recommended. I find it both hilarious and interesting:

https://youtu.be/XURRzofbMc0

**Lethality of misuse**

Would misuse of *nigger* lead to actual bodily harm or death? Although it's possible, it's highly unlikely. However, I firmly believe that its inappropriate use can effectively lead to a type of *social death*.

One example of this is the end of the stand-up comedy career of Michael Richards, who played the character Kramer in the TV comedy series *Seinfeld* after he used *nigger* in a comedy routine.

Comment: How is 'nigger' a term of endearment?  Please provide source & example.

Comment: @TrevorD It's a terrible example since it's the exact same word and sense, but one black man can say it to another in the same way most insults can be used ironically or affectionately. ("You dummy", "you varlet", "you little monkey", "you dirty whore", "you right cunt", &c.) It does not have antipodal meanings for people to whom it cannot be applied, just the one.

Comment: ^ no, i believe "nigger" can be used to connote "brotherhood" in an entirely non-pejorative sense.

Comment: Where I lived in NYC, calling a black person "my nigga" as a white man would probably get you a high five if you were close friends, a funny look if you knew each other and were friendly but not really friends, and shot if you didn't know them.

Comment: Rush Hour Whats up my nigga? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyXuP48LDOE

Answer (score 3):

How about 'resign' ?

*Arsenal fans devastated as Wenger resigns*

This could either mean he quits his job by *resigning* from it, or commits his future to it by *re-signing* with the team.

Comment: Any careful writer would use "re-signs" if they meant "signs again".

Comment: Indeed, but an incompetent one might not :)

Comment: I didn't even understand the issue here without the comment from @DavidRicherby.  We are not all football fansand I couldn't see how "resigns" means "commits his future".  I suggest amplifying your answer.

Comment: I've edited to answer to clarify it as proposed.

Comment: Not altogether lethal, though.

Answer (score 2):

"execution". Very positive meaning in planning, but with the secondary meaning of judicially sanctioned murder....

Comment: Provide an example, if you please.

Comment: On a site like engrish.com, I saw something like "customers will be executed in the order they arrived".

Answer (score 2):

Any case where the same word is used for a person's or animals job or role and a machine/tool/implement/software product (or its brand) could end in serious tragedy at least:

"Not willing to work with this editor for a minute longer" — not good in a company that has computers and people writing news copy.

"Throw out the foreman!" — both a brand of grill and the chief on a crew of workers

"The watchdog is full of bugs, kill it!" — a computer program or a canine?

"This aviation show is not going on TV since the pilot failed."

"This driver regularly crashes the bus" — this could describe a computer hardware problem or traffic accidents ... and be a confusing problem description in automotive software!

Answer (score 1):

I have two examples to offer.

The first is not so much English, as visual, but definitely can lead to a dangerous situation in normal life:

- In the UK, the road sign for "Cycling Forbidden" is a red circle with a bicycle symbol inside:
  [image: List item]

  But I have met people (mostly teenagers or people who don't drive) who honestly believe this means "Official Cycle Route".

  You would expect cycling to be forbidden in places where it is dangerous to do so, so obviously this signage could be improved (most common suggestion being to put a red line through it the circle.)

The second suggestion may not lead to physical danger, but could be socially awkward or embarrassing:

- I've met foreign-language speakers who confuse **sensible** and **sensitive**, for example, if they say: *"I've very sensible about your position."*

Comment: The sign isn't a word and confusing sensible/sensitive has no serious consequences.

Comment: Sensible / sensitive have, for whatever reasons, exchanged meaning in different languages. So in French, "sensible" really does mean "sensitive". It's a common example of a "false friend", of which there are many when learning languages.

Comment: Or in the title **Sense and Sensibility** where one sister had more SENSE(practicality, self-command) and the other had more SENSIBILITY, which meant she was more driven by her emotions. We would describe her as SENSITIVE today(in the U.S.)

Comment: http://www.shakespeare-online.com/plays/macbeth/soliloquies/sensible.html

Comment: While I don't disagree that some signs can be confusing, the UK signs (roughly) follow a European standard.  **All** signs with a red circle denote prohibition.

Comment: I know that, but so what? It doesn't communicate. But anyway, this is off-topic now.

Comment: The red circle sign (with a person in it) lead me to run on a train-only section of track in a foreign country. Americans like me get confused by signs like these.

Answer (score 1):

> What word if not used competently could end up leading to injury or death in a context that most people could understand with little-to-no explanation?

The word is "**ok**".

Well, this example does require a somewhat elaborate explanation, but the use of the word "ok" by an air traffic controller was a contributing factor in the [Tenerife airport disaster](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster) in 1977, a collision of two planes that killed 583 people and was the deadliest accident in aviation history.

More generally, the events leading to the collision involved several language-based communication failures that led to the decision of the pilot of one of the planes to begin a takeoff roll despite not receiving an official clearance to take off from air traffic control. The nonstandard use of the word "ok" by the air traffic controller was apparently one of the possible sources of the confusion. As Wikipedia explains:

> The controller, who could not see the runway due to the fog, initially responded with "OK" (terminology which is nonstandard), which reinforced the KLM captain's misinterpretation that they had takeoff clearance. The controller's response of "OK" to the co-pilot's nonstandard statement that they were "now at takeoff" was likely due to his misinterpretation that they were in takeoff position and ready to begin the roll when takeoff clearance was received, but not in the process of taking off.

As I said, the full analysis of the causes of he accident is a lot more complicated. The Wikipedia article has a detailed account of this tragic event, which incidentally led to a serious reform of radio communication procedures for pilots and controllers (including the implementation of strict rules regarding when specific words such as "takeoff" may be used).

Indeed, even after that reform, poor verbal communication has been a direct cause or a contributing factor in many aviation accidents, though the Tenerife airport disaster is clearly the most dramatic and tragic example. The folks over at [aviation.stackexchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) will surely know about many more stories illustrating the crucial importance of communication in aviation safety.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a French person seeking a bottle of fish juice might drink from a bottle marked with the English word "Poison".
(The French "Poisson" meaning "fish")

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [explain your answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), preferably with some supporting statements and [references](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.

Comment: No, because "poison" is also French for poison.

Comment: But an English person might open a German box that says *Gift*.

Comment: Urban legends abound of german customs&imports getting badly confused by that :)

Answer (score 0):

Death, probably not, but level of pain inflicted, highly dependant.

If I, an Englishman, pinch a woman's fanny I'm likely to be kicked soundly in the groin, whereas if an American pinches a woman's fanny he might get away with being slapped.

In order to avoid damage to my family jewels I would have to turn her around and pinch her bum. Oh dear, there I go again. I mean her bottom, not the neighbourhood homeless man.

This is why the British have bum bags, whilst Americans have fanny packs.

Comment: This is an example of slang differentiation, and not incompetence.

Comment: I like the joke, but it doesn't belong to this question :-(

Answer (score 0):

The word 'five' is generally omitted from countdowns for warfare or similar given its similarity to the word 'fire'

e.g. Six... ... Four... Three.. Two...

Comment: Five is right out!

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 0):

Go with "[sanguine](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sanguine)".

> adjective
>
> 1. cheerfully optimistic, hopeful, or confident: a sanguine disposition; sanguine expectations.
> 2. bloody; sanguinary.

The juxtaposition between its meanings for both hopeful and bloody make it a cinch for this kind of use.  The phrase "I'm looking for a sanguine resolution of this situation" could mean either a positive outcome or something more along the lines of "shoot everyone in the head."

Hopeful or bloody... it's a word that really covers all your options. :)

Answer (score -1):

"Beat" has constructive meanings in music, construction, and cooking ... and some concerning assault or disapproval...

"The yoghurt is curdling when I add it to the heated sauce" ..."Beat it!"

"They didn't get the texture of these biscuits right" .."I agree, they need to be beaten!"

Comment: In that ultimate example, sn't that syntactical confusion, though?  I take it you meant confusing the object of the **it** pronoun with the head and not the iron ingot.

Comment: Removed the ultimate example (dude, you just created another example :: :) ) because yes, it is confusing...

Answer (score -1):

"load".

- Put stuff in a vehicle or ship or means of storage, run computer programs .... mostly harmless.
- put strain on construction or electrical equipment ... can go wrong if overdone
- Make a firearm operational ... mostly not harmless at all.

Answer (score -1):

An innocent man with unfortunate luck in the courts stands before a firing squad and pleads for his life.

The captain, an hardened officer with no patience for drama, calmly says "Ready." His the squad prepares to fire.

The captain nonchalantly orders: "Aim" and the squad levels their rifles.

Suddenly, an red-faced courier arrives with a last-minute commutation from the local magistrate. The captain reads the letter with disappointment. "Ah, shoot."

Answer (score -1):

John lives with and takes care of his elderly mother.  In order for John to go on a vacation, John's brother, Carl, volunteers to help with the care of their mother.  John verbally lists all the daily tasks that Carl will need to do to help their mother--Carl won't need to stay there but will have to check in at least a couple times every day.

One of the instructions that John gives Carl regards their mother's medicines.  "She has four prescriptions waiting for pickup tomorrow at the pharmacist.  You'll need to pick those up so you can give them to her."  The next day, Carl goes to the pharmacist and gets the prescription refills.  He takes them to the mother's residence and sets them on the counter, telling her where they are.  After completing his other chores, Carl leaves for the night.  The next day, Carl finds his mother in a bad medical state.

When John used the word **give**, he intended for Carl to make sure the medicines were administered to the mother.  Carl took it as meaning to hand over possession of.  He didn't realize that the elderly woman had trouble remembering how and when to take her prescriptions.

Answer (score -1):

> 1— What did you do with the damaged part of the engine?
>
> 2— I have simply replaced it.
>
> 1— Fine, you can restart operations then.

...Of course if "replace" in the mind of 2 means "Put (something) back in a previous place or position" while it is "Provide a substitute for (something that is broken, old, or inoperative)", then restarting operations may be very dangerous...

Answer (score -2):

**Alcohol**

In general use, a drink, as in "I'll be drinking alcohol tonight, so I should not drive".

In a chemist's usage, alcohol describes a range of compounds, many of which would kill or maim a human if swallowed.

Comment: -1 "Alcohol" is a term for a class / group of compounds which includes *both* (i) ingredients in alcoholic drinks; and (ii) many other substances not generally drunk.  In fact, the alcoholic components of alcoholic drink could lead to serious harm of death if drunk in sufficient concentration.  So this is **not** an example of a word with multiple - and possibly conflicting - meanings as asked for in the Q.: it is merely an issue of the concentration of the alcoholic ingredient.